# How do I collapse selected chunks of code in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2008: Is there a way for me to customly collapse bits of code similar to like how I can automatically collapse chunks of comments?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your piece of code needs to be a block surrounded by, as desired:

- braces
- `#region` and `#endregion` in C#
- `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` in C/C++

If you can't collapse statement blocks, you need to enable this feature :

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> check everything in "outlining"

(In Visual Studio 2013 it's Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> View)

Then, reopen the source file to reload outlining.

Comment: Hmm, well it works, but unfortuatly it is essentaly commenting the entire chunk of code out of my program. I want to be able to collapse working code. This is especialy usefull when i want to add a condition (an if statement) to activate a large chunk of code without putting it into a function (it dosent work as a function, so i dident make it as one).

Comment: Its more of like putting in new if statements. There are simply too many loops in my program (i think its at around 10 nested loops + a whole bunch of other if statements) and its beocmming hard to keep track of what is inside of what. How do i collapse loops and if statements?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it is commenting out the code. You should be able to use the #pragma regions statements to create collapsible chunks of working code.

Answer (score 6):

TheSam is right, you can create collapsible chunks with the #pragma region and #pragma endregion statements.

Here is a sample:

```
int main(array<System::String> args)
{


    Console::WriteLine(L"This");
    Console::WriteLine(L"is");
    Console::WriteLine(L"a");
    #pragma region
    Console::WriteLine(L"pragma");
    Console::WriteLine(L"region");
    #pragma endregion

    Console::WriteLine(L"test.");
    return 0;
}
```

In the above sample, everything between the samples can be collapsed.

You can also specify what text is displayed when it is collapsed. You can do that like this:

```
#pragma region The displayed text
```

That would obviously display "The displayed text" when the region was collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is made for the job in Visual Studio:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8

Comment: @Amjad - the developer states in the Q&A that its a quick fix in the source to work with C++/C code.  You will just need to change language affinity attribute evidently.  I only use VisStudio for C#,  Javascript and PHP so haven't tried it.
Link to source code of the extension is here:
https://github.com/Skybladev2/C--outline-for-Visual-Studio