# Hide sections of code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This question isn't directly related to coding, but more to do with the efficiency and organisation of the c++ code. I have loads of declarations of arrays with preset data so they take up quite a lot of space.

I don't know whether this is a visual studio 2012 only feature but with functions I am able to minimise it so all I see is the name "void randomfunction()", this means I really speed up coding by collapsing all functions that I know are done and dusted for the time being.

What I would like to know if this is possible with any other parts of the code, like when you want to add a comment you // before typing. Is it possible to define two boundaries around a chunk of code so that I can collapse it.

Ok thanks guys for help im using the #pragma region #pragma endregion commands, how would i name the region so that if i create multiple i can know which is which whithout opening?

Comment: Put them in a separate file? It also avoids recompiling those arrays when the rest of the code changes.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by new file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626036/how-do-i-collapse-selected-chunks-of-code-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: I updated the tag to visual-studio rather than C++ since this isn't a C++ question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000479/equivalent-of-region-for-c - you can use #pragma Region (assuming you're using VS).

Comment: @MarkB well it is a c++ question if this feature is not available in other visual studio languages or it is available in other c++ IDEs

Comment: @MarkB It is a c++ question in addition to being a VS question: different languages have different preprocessor commands. I'm used to using #region/#endregion for this, but that only works in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
#pragma region "My region name"
```

And it will work.

However, if you find yourself in a need to hide code, that means *your functions are too long*. You should divide your code logically without resorting to hacks like these.

Comment: He specifically said what he wanted to be able to collapse: a long constant list. How exactly would you "divide your code logically" in a long list of constants? I can't think of anything. :p
(Well, I suppose putting them in a separate file, but sometimes you don't want to.)

Comment: @neminem In that case putting it in a separate header would be a reasonable solution. Also when answering on SO you're answering to the whole community, not only the OP. I don't want newbies abusing `#pragma region` (I did that myself `:(`)

Comment: It seems you must use `#pragma endregion "My region name"` to be able to collapse the code chunk.

Answer (score 1):

This is called code folding. In visual studi there are hotkeys that are described here
[Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code)
For C++, any scope block {} can be folded separately...

Comment: To piggyback on this answer, VS stores which scope blocks are folded in your .user profile file, and will keep them folded the next time you open the file.