# VS2010: Collapse code regions only works for .c files, not for .cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I would like to be able to collapse functions and statements in c++. At the moment I am only able to do that in .c files, not in .cpp files.
I have all the settings in `TextEditor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Advanced -> Outlining` set to TRUE.
Any idea what else could work?

Comment: Do you mean code regions as in *#pragma region* or bits within {} and /* */

Comment: I mean code within `{}` and `/* */`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626036/how-do-i-collapse-selected-chunks-of-code-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some conditions to collapse code blocks, your code should be sourrounded by one of these:

- braces
- `#region` and `#endregion` in C#
- `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` in C/C++

If you can't collapse statement blocks, you need to enable this feature :

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> check
>   everything in "outlining"

Then, reopen the source file to reload outlining.

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626053/1938163)

Comment: Didnt reload the file. Thanks!